# F# List.exists on two lists

Tags: f#

I have two lists `listA` and `listB` where I want to return `true` if `listB` contains any element also in `listA`.

```
let listA = ["A";"B";"C"]
let listB = ["D";"E";"A"]
```

Should return `true` in this case. I feel like this should be easy to solve and I'm missing something fundamental somewhere.

For example, why can't I do like this?

```
let testIntersect = for elem in listA do List.exists (fun x -> x = elem) listB
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't write something like your example code because a plain `for` doesn't return a result, it just evaluates an expression for its side-effects.  You could write the code in a `for` comprehension:

```
let testIntersect listA listB = 
    [for elem in listA do yield List.exists (fun x -> x = elem) listB]
```

Of course, this then returns a `bool list` rather than a single `bool`.

> ```
> val testIntersect :
>   listA:seq<'a> -> listB:'a list -> bool list when 'a : equality
>
> let listA = ["A";"B";"C"]
> let listB = ["D";"E";"A"]
>
> testIntersect listA listB
> val it : bool list = [true; false; false]
> ```

So, we can use the `List.exists` function to ensure that a `true` occurs at least once:

```
let testIntersect listA listB = 
    [for elem in listA do yield List.exists (fun x -> x = elem) listB]
    |> List.exists id
```

> ```
> val testIntersect :
>   listA:seq<'a> -> listB:'a list -> bool list when 'a : equality
>
> val listA : string list = ["A"; "B"; "C"]
> val listB : string list = ["D"; "E"; "A"]
> val it : bool = false
> ```

---

It's pretty inefficient to solve this problem using `List` though, it's better to use `Set`.  With `Set`, you can calculate intersection in **O(log N * log M)** time rather than **O(N*M)**.

```
let testSetIntersect listA listB =
    Set.intersect (Set.ofList listA) (Set.ofList listB)
    |> Set.isEmpty
    |> not
```

Answer (score 3):

One function that you could use is `List.except`, which is not yet documented (!) but can be seen in [this pull request](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/pull/253) that was merged a couple of years ago. You'd probably use it like this:

```
let testIntersect a b =
    let b' = b |> List.except a
    // If b' is shorter than b, then b contained at least one element of a
    List.length b' < List.length b
```

However, this runs through list B about three times, once to do the `except` algorithm and once each to do both the `length` calls. So another approach might be to do what you did, but turn list A into a set so that the `exists` call won't be O(N):

```
let testIntersect a b =
    let setA = a |> Set.ofList
    match b |> List.tryFind (fun x -> setA |> Set.contains x) with
    | Some _ -> true
    | None   -> false
```

The reason I used `tryFind` is because `List.find` would throw an exception if the predicate didn't match any items of the list.

**Edit:** An even better approach is to use `List.exists`, which I temporarily forgot about (thanks to Honza Brestan for reminding me about it):

```
let testIntersect a b =
    let setA = a |> Set.ofList
    b |> List.exists (fun x -> setA |> Set.contains x)
```

Which, of course, is pretty much what you were originally wanting to do in your `testIntersect` code sample. The only difference is that you were using the `for ... in` syntax in your code sample, which wouldn't work. In F#, the `for` loop is *exclusively* for expressions that return `unit` (and thus, probably have side effects). If you want to return a value, the `for` loop won't do that. So using the functions that *do* return value, like `List.exists`, is the approach you want to take.

Comment: I like the second approach, but can't you simplify the search to use `List.exists` instead of `tryFind`? I think the exact same predicate can be used and you'll get rid of the `match`.

Comment: @HonzaBrestan - Good idea! I don't know why I didn't consider `List.exists`, especially since the OP used it in his (not quite correct) sample code. Actually, that's probably why I didn't consider it. :-) I've updated my answer to incorporate your excellent suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

```
let testIntersect listA listB = 
    (Set.ofList listA) - (Set.ofList listB) |> Set.isEmpty |> not
```